# jquery not function miss element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use a tool-tip to display error message on the page, I need it to be closed when I click elsewhere within the view. I use the below codes to control this action:

```
$(':not(.qtip)').click(function(){
   $('.qtip').hide();
});
```

The ".qtip" is used for marking the tool-tip area. The tool-tip itself creates a new one when it comes out, what happened here is when I click on the tool-tip, it disappears.

But when I use a smaller scale of the selector instead of the whole body, it works fine, which is a little weird, for example:

```
$("#id").not('.qtip').click(function (){
    $('.qtip').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be advisable to just target `document` for handling the click outside of your tooltip; the selector for `:not(.qtip)` potentially returns a very big result set.

```
$(document).on('click', function() {
    $('.qtip').hide();
}
```

On the tooltip itself you would need to prevent the click event from bubbling to document level, if you're not doing so yet:

```
$('.qtip').on('click', false);
```

Comment: It will hide qtip, even if the click was inside it.

Comment: @Sylvanus Good point, though I'm not sure whether OP is already handling the click event on qtip itself.

Comment: I tried these codes but it didn't work, seems that the click event didn't bind to the qtip elements

Comment: @Tim so what happens instead?

Comment: it still hides when I click it

Comment: @Jack plus, my jQuery version is 1.3.1

Comment: I solved this problem by using parents() function to check if the target is within the qtip area, avoided the bubbling.  if(!($(event.target).parents('.qtip').length>0)){
        $('.qtip').hide();
       }

Answer (score 1):

Use event bubbling to your advantage

```
$(document).on("mouseup", function (e) {
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    var container = $(".qtip");

    if (container.not(target) && container.has(target).length === 0)
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I solved this problem by using parents() function to check if the target is within the qtip area, avoided the bubbling. if(!($(event.target).parents('.qtip').length>0)){ $('.qtip').hide(); }

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to do two things:

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $('.qtip').hide();
});


$('.qtip').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

1. click of document to hide the `.qtip`
2. stop the event bubbling on click of `.qtip`, here click won't traverse up to the parent.

Comment: I tried this code, but it seems that the click event still bubbling, I didn't figure out why it happened

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
    var qtip = $(e.target).closest('.qtip');
    if(!qtip.length)
        $('.qtip').hide();
});
```